# Is possible to use "snap to grid" when using a camera in perspective?

Tags: snapping

"snap to grid" only seems to work if I'm using the orthogonal view, if I use it on perspective mode, my objects move way too much.

Or, there is a way to move objects only cm by cm in perspective mode?

Comment: Try holding the *shift* key when moving. It isn't snap-to-grid, but it should slow down your mouse movement.

Comment: I know about that but I'm searching for something more aimed at precision modeling